# Is unpacking variadic using array(or initializer_list) trick optimize-safe?

Tags: c++, optimization, c++14, variadic, argument-unpacking

Since C++14 cannot use fold expression, in order to make a function that calls `bar` on each variadics, one have to use function overloading.

```
template<typename Arg>
void foo(Arg arg) {
  bar(arg);
}

template<typename Arg, typename ...Args>
void foo(Arg arg, Args... args) {
  bar(arg);
  foo(args...);
}
```

But using comma operator and parenthesis in bracket, one can unpack without overload.

```
template<typename ...Args>
void foo(Args... args) {
  int dummy[] = {
    (bar(args), 0)...
  };
}
```

It works well as expected, but my compiler always warns me that `dummy` is not used.
So I'm worried that the compiler removes `dummy`(since it's unused and actually initialized only by literals), and resulting to not calling `bar`.
Or just declaring `dummy` as `volatile` is enough to be guarantee that `bar` is called?
I know that there is `[[maybe_unused]]` attribute, but it's also C++17 feature.

Comment: what is "optimize safe" ? Are you worried that optimizations could remove the unused part and by this change the behavior of your code?

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 yes I'm worried if the compiler removes `dummy` and resulting to not calling `bar`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So I'm worried that the compiler removes `dummy`(since it's unused and actually initialized only by literals), and resulting to not calling `bar`.

Compiler might remove `dummy` but cannot remove `bar` calls if they have side effects (as for the recursive version).

So you are safe.

> Or just declaring `dummy` as `volatile`"

That is worst. As you force the write. You remove the warning the wrong way.

> I know that there is `[[maybe_unused]]` attribute, but it's also C++17 feature.

Casting to `void` is a common way to remove the warning, previously.

Answer (score 1):

no worry, the compiler optimizations won't break the code behavior otherwise the compiler is broken, however there is copy eliding and such which changes the behavior in a documented way .

in your case the the call will be evaluated and the return value stored in the array is discarded. since this is your intention you can get rid of this warning by using the variable !

`((void)dummy);`